# Conditions on Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

In Shiryaev's probability, the formulation of the monotone convergence theorem is as such:

> Let $ \eta, \xi,  \xi_1, x_2, \ldots$ be random variables. If $\xi_n
>  \geq \eta$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\mathbb{E}\eta > -\infty$ and $\xi_n
>  \uparrow \xi$, then $\mathbb{E}\xi_n \uparrow\mathbb{E}\xi$.

My question is: why is $\mathbb{E}\eta > -\infty$ necessary? Is there a situation where I can construct a sequence as in the statement of the theorem with a random variable where $\mathbb{E}\eta = -\infty$ that makes the MCT fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this condition is necessary.  Otherwise, you could have $\mathbb{E}[\xi_n] = -\infty$ for all $n$, but $\mathbb{E}[\xi] = 0$.  For example, if we consider the probability space $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and let $\xi_n(x) := -\frac 1x 1_{(0,\frac 1n)}$, then $\mathbb{E}[\xi_n] = \int_0^{1/n} -\frac{1}{x}dx = -\infty$.  However, $\xi_n(x)$ is a non-decreasing sequence with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \xi_n(x) = 0$ so $\xi = 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[\xi] = 0$.